# Correct lambda filter implementation

Tags: java, list, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a case where I need to

- `map` an object, if the mapping function throws an exception, I map it to `null`.
- `filter` the mapped stream for `null` object, if null then throw Exception, else collect to List.

How would I achieve this?

```
list.stream().map(ob-> {
    try {
        // cannot throw only catch 
        return function(ob);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e);
        return null;
    }            
}).filter(Objects::isNull).findFirst().orElseThrow(Exception::new);
```

Now my question is how should I tweak/refactor the above lambda to `throw new Exception()` on `null` or else `collect(Collectors.toList())`.

Comment: What is the purpose of throwing a checked exception here?

Comment: You *can* throw from lambda bodies, but only `RuntimeException`s, no checked exceptions. In this case, however, I would choose a loop instead of the stream, because it will be a lot simpler to read and debug.

Comment: A better approach would be to handle the `Exception` within your `function(ob)` and things would be a lot simpler then.... btw, what's the `findFirst` in our code existing for?

Answer (score 6):

If you intend to report the exception (which is a good idea), you should never map it to `null` in the first place. Since certain functional interfaces do not allow to throw a checked exception, you should rethrow it wrapped in an unchecked exception:

```
try {
    List<Object> result = list.stream().map(ob-> {
        try {
            // cannot throw checked exception types
            return function(ob);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new CompletionException(e);
        }
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
} catch(CompletionException ex) {
    throw (Exception)ex.getCause();
}
```

The key point is that this will throw the original exception, with all information contained within it, instead of creating a new instance via `new Exception()` that would contain no information about the cause at all.

Note that for some cases, there are already dedicated exception types, e.g. `UncheckedIOException` to wrap an `IOException`. In other cases, it might be cleaner to declare your own unchecked exception type, to be sure that it doesn’t get mixed up with other exceptions thrown by other components of your application.

Answer (score 3):

You can partition by a predicate and throw an exception if the map contains a non-empty collection for the `null` key:

```
Map<Boolean, List<String>> resultMap = list.stream().map(ob-> {
    try {
        return function(ob);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}).collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(Objects::isNull));

if(!resultMap.get(Boolean.TRUE).isEmpty()) {
    throw new Exception();
}

return resultMap.get(Boolean.FALSE);
```

`Collectors.partitioningBy(Objects::isNull)` will return a `Map<Boolean, List<T>>` where `true` will be mapped to a list with all elements that matched the predicate (`Objects::isNull`), and `false` to those that didn't.

If the `true` collection is not empty, you know you can raise the exception.

Answer (score 3):

Well, there is possible to work with `try-catch` clauses inside lambdas, yet it's not recommended since the lambdas should stay as short as possible.

Separate the mapper to the new method and call it in the lambda instead.

```
private static final <T, R> R tryMapOrElseNull(T t) {
    try {
        return function(t);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        this.log.error(e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then use the method as a method reference in the `Stream::map` method. Firstly, collect the newly mapped elements and then just simply check for `null`.

```
newList = list.stream().map(MyClass::safeMap).collect(Collectors.toList());

if (newList.contains(null)) {
    throw new Exception();
}
```

Comment: `newList.stream().filter(Objects::isNull).findFirst().isPresent()` can be simplified to `newList.stream().anyMatch(Objects::isNull)` or just `newList.contains(null)`.

Comment: @Holger: My `java-stream` unhealthy obsession is real. Of course and thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

I would throw a exception and leave right now the stream processing if I detect that I don't need to iterate next elements. Why going on performing logic if it is helpless ?

So I would not use built-in `map()` in this case and not stream either. 
I think that it would make things very readable by introducing a simple method to do the mapping :

```
try{
    return map(list);
} 
catch (Exception e) {
    throw new AnyExceptionYouWant(e);
}

// helper method
List<Bar> map (List<Foo> list) throws Exception{
   List<Bar>> bars = new ArrayList<>();       
   for (Foo foo : list){
          bars.add(function(foo));
   }
   return bars;
 }
```

If you want to use readable and easy to maintain streams, you should probably not throw any exception in `function()`. You could for example return a List of `Optional`s and so it would be simple to handle the empty case in your stream.

Comment: As long as the operation is as simple as a single `map` step followed by collecting into a `List`, an ordinary loop might be a viable alternative. You can even tune it by using `new ArrayList<>(list.size());`, an optimization which the Stream will not do.

Comment: It is right. I didn't think of this optimization that besides documents the mapping intention (one to one mapping).

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this in two steps, first collect to a list:

```
List<T> result = list.stream().map(ob -> {
                try {
                    // cannot throw only catch, since lambda expression 
                    return function(ob);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.error(e);
                    return null;
                }
            }).collect(toList());
```

where `T` is the type of elements being mapped to.

then check for nullity:

```
if(result.contains(null)) {/* throw exeception... */}
else { /* do something else */}
```